# Multiple IntegrationFlows attached to the same request channel in Gateway method

Tags: spring-integration

Given I have application which uses Spring Integration and I define gateway:

```
@Component
@MessagingGateway
public interface SmsGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = CHANNEL_SEND_SMS)
    void sendSms(SendSmsRequest request);
}

public interface IntegrationChannels {
    String CHANNEL_SEND_SMS = "channelSendSms";
}
```

I also attach `IntegrationFlow` to `CHANNEL_SEND_SMS` channel:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendSmsFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL_SEND_SMS)
            .transform(...)
            .handle(...)
            .get();
}
```

Whenever I call `sendSms` gateway method from business code, `sendSmsFlow` is executed as expected.

When I want to attach another `IntegrationFlow` to the same `CHANNEL_SEND_SMS` channel, e.g.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow differentFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL_SEND_SMS)
            .transform(...)
            .handle(...)
            .get();
}
```

then this `differentFlow` is not executed.

Why does it behave this way?

Is there any solution to make it work for both flows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default channel type is `DirectChannel` and messages are distributed to multiple subscribed channels in a round robin fashion by default.

Declare `CHANNEL_SEND_SMS` as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` if you want each flow to get every message.

This will only work with a `void` gateway method; if there is a return type, you will get the first (or random if there is any async downstream processing) and the others will be discarded.